# How to cast from parent to interface of chlid class

Tags: c++, interface, casting, polymorphism, multiple-inheritance

Say I have a parent class `Parent` and child classes `Child1` and `Child2` having the latter implementing `MyInterface`:

```
class Parent {
    public:
        Parent();
        virtual ~Parent();
        virtual void MyMethod();
}
class MyInterface {
    public:
        virtual ~MyInterface() {}
        virtual void MyInterfaceMethod() = 0;
}
class Child1 : public Parent {
    public:
        Child1();
        virtual ~Child1();
}
class Child2 : public Parent, MyInterface {
    public:
        Child2();
        virtual ~Child2();
        virtual void MyInterfaceMethod() override;
}
```

And say I'm given a `Parent*` pointer, and I want to check if the object is implementing `MyInterface` and if yes, cast it to `MyInterface*`.

I've tried to achieve it this way:

```
void MyFunction(Parent* p) {
    MyInterface* i = dynamic_cast<MyInterface*>(p);
    if (i != 0)
        DoSomething();
    else
        cout << "Cannot do anything.";
}
```

But i always equals to 0 which says it is never casted to the type `MyInterface*` even if I know for sure that the object has the good type.

How should I achieve this?

Comment: What's against polymorphism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Child2` `private` inherits from `MyInterface`, unless `MyFunction()` has the privilege to access the `private` base subobject, `dynamic_cast` will always fail.

Since `MyInterface` seems to be an *interface*, I think you want `public` inheritance.

```
class Child2 : public Parent, public MyInterface { }
//                            ~~~~~~
```

[LIVE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/baa37ed0a08a606b) (Other errors fixed)

Comment: Are you sure about that? Methinks it's due to the fact that the classes are not polymorphic types as they are missing a virtual function.

Comment: @Bathsheba I'm sure, almost. Because if `Parent` is not polymorphic type OP will get a compiler error. OP said "i always equals to 0" so I suppose it's a runtime issue. (Of course `Parent` should be polymorphic.)

Comment: The minimized code example has both problems, but this is more likely to be the issue in the real code.

Comment: having private Parent inheritance gets you a compiler error too upon trying to pass a Child2 object as a Parent pointer.

Comment: @GillBates Yes, it's another error in OP's example.

Comment: Many thanks, that did the trick, didn't notice I had to specify "public" for each inheritance. Also, I didn't even know why it was mandatory to specify this, I don't understand why an inheritance would be private. I'm coming from the C# world where all this is done with less keywords, so I'm a bit lost and I'm confused that I missed important pieces of code in the code sample. I wrote this quickly to ask question because original code is too long for a simple copy/paste.

Answer (score 1):

Your classes must be *polymorphic types* for `dynamic_cast` to work.

The simplest way of achieving this is to add

`virtual ~Parent() = default;`

in the `public` area of the `Parent` class. Then the `dynamic_cast` will sniff around the inheritance tree for your interface like a truffling pig.

Comment: You'll want to explicitly make Parents constructor default too otherwise it'll be implicitly deleted.

Comment: Didn't have to set the destructor to default to make my code work, but I'd love to understand what this `= default` does?

Comment: It's a C++11 thing. Google the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, instead of using `dynamic_cast`, we could use the [Visitor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern):

```
#include <iostream>

class MyInterface {
public:
    virtual void DoSomething() = 0;
};

class Parent {
public:
    virtual ~Parent() = default;
    virtual void accept(class Visitor& visitor) = 0;
};

class Child1 : public Parent {
public:
    virtual void accept(Visitor& visitor);
};

class Child2 : public Parent, public MyInterface {
public:
    virtual void accept(Visitor& visitor);
    virtual void DoSomething();
};

class Visitor
{
public:
    void visit(Child1& child);
    void visit(Child2& child);
};

void Child1::accept(Visitor& visitor) { visitor.visit(*this); }
void Child2::accept(Visitor& visitor) { visitor.visit(*this); }
void Child2::DoSomething() { std::cout << "Do something.\n"; }

void Visitor::visit(Child1& child) { std::cout << "Cannot do anything.\n"; }
void Visitor::visit(Child2& child) { child.DoSomething(); }

void MyFunction(Parent& p) {
    Visitor v;
    p.accept(v);
}

int main()
{
    Child1 c1;
    Child2 c2;
    MyFunction(c1);
    MyFunction(c2);
}
```

Output:

`Cannot do anything.`

`Do something.`